# Prove homogeneous inequality

Tags: inequality

Prove that for all $a,b,c>0$ we have $$\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{bc}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{ac}{(a+c)^2}\leq\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}.$$

Please help me prove this homogeneous inequality.

Comment: Consider this observation that might come in handy (justing pointing out another way of trying to approach this in case you haven't tried it): $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc$$

Comment: Are you sure is it OK?

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
D=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}-
\Bigg(\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{bc}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{ac}{(a+c)^2}\Bigg) \tag{1}
$$

We must show that $D$ is nonnegative. It will suffice to show
that

$$
D=\frac{1}{4}.\frac{(b-a)^2(c-a)^2(c-b)^2}{(a+b)^2(b+c)^2(c+a)^2} \tag{2}
$$

But this follows easily enough from the expanding the identity

$$
(b-a)^2(c-a)^2(c-b)^2=((b+a)^2-4ab)((c+a)^2-4ac)((c+b)^2-4bc)
$$

(I do not put in all the details as this is homework).

Comment: That *identity* is wrong...

Comment: @chubakueno corrected, thanks.

Comment: $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \ge 0 $ is trivial, why you need to expand it ?

Comment: @chenbai I need to expand it in order to prove (2), as written in the post.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy,I got it. you gave the hint to op how you get (2).