# Having problem proving a statement

Tags: inequality

> I have a problem  proving the following  for $a,b,c>0$
>   $$\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{bc}{(b+c)^2} + \frac{ac}{(a+c)^2} \le \frac{1}{5} + \frac{4abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}.$$

Comment: Hi @user573666, this website is not for these type of questions. You need to show what effort you have put to solve the problem. Your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839075/given-xy-144-xy-30-and-x-y-solve-x-y) also received a lot of down votes.

Answer (score 2):

Counter Example $a=b=c=1$ ... $\frac{3}{4} \leq \frac{1}{5} +\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Edit :
Note that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a-ab^2-bc^2-ca^2)^2 \geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
can be rearranged to give
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a+c)^2(b+c)^2(a+b)^2+16abc(a+c)(b+c)(a+b)\geq 4( ab(a+c)^2(b+c)^2+ac(a+b)^2(b+c)^2+cb(a+c)^2(b+a)^2).
\end{eqnarray*}
So the question would have worked if it had been
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{bc}{(b+c)^2} + \frac{ac}{(a+c)^2} \le \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}} + \frac{4abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: That corrected version has been asked before : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802849/prove-homogeneous-inequality